# Can webpack2 load modules dynamically like SystemJS

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

webpack1 didn't have the ability to load modules on demand like I can do it with `SystemJS`:

```
function a() {
    var moduleName = getDynamicModuleName();
    SystemJS.import(moduleName).then(function (m) {
        console.log(m);
    });
}
```

Based [on this article](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#code-splitting-with-es2015) it seems that `webpack2` can do that as well, so I put up the following:

```
function a() {
    var moduleName = getDynamicModuleName();
    import(moduleName).then(function (m) {

    });
}
```

However, webpack created the bundle for `moduleName` and gave the warning:

```
3:4-22 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

So this is not exactly dynamic, it's the way code splitting works. So does webpack2 support true dynamic loading like SystemJS?

Comment: You can have a look at: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: @mrlew, these docs are for webpack1

Comment: @mrlew, this question is not about code splitting, but about loading modules unknown during build time on demand

Comment: Does `moduleName` refer to a javascript file that's hosted on the site along with the bundle, or is it a module that webpack has bundled at build time?

Comment: @StefanDragnev, it refers to a file determined during runtime and which can be loaded from other domains and is unknown during build time. Also, it's possible that there will be an array of modules to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is a bundler, it's not a loader. It provides a number of loader-like functions like `require` and `import` so that bundled modules can interact with each other, but that's about it. What you're looking for is an actual loader.

One possibility is to use webpack's `script-loader`:

`` require(`script!${moduleUrl}`, function() {
...
}) ``

Another possibility is to use an actual loader independently of webpack, like, for example `little-loader`:

`var load = require("little-loader");
load("http://example.com/foo.js", function (err) {
  // ... your code ...
});`

Comment: ok, thanks, but once loaded, how can I integrate the loaded module into webpack modules system? For example, require loaded module in some other modules after the load?

Comment: It doesn't have to - webpack's module system works essentially only with whatever is bundled at build time. But you can use your dynamic loader of choice in all bundled modules.